# No retiene la ejecución o ventana del código en Python

Tags: python

El siguiente código no muestra error, sin embargo no se retiene la ejecución, la ventana se muestra y automáticamente se oculta, comparto el siguiente código

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from segunda import Ui_segunda

qtCreatorFile = "principal.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

    def abrir(self):
        self.ventana=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_segunda()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.ventana)
        self.ventana.show()


if ____name____ == "____main____":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
```

---

efectivamente anexé el siguiente código app.exec_() y funcionó.

Comment: No se nada de Qt, pero no habria que iniciar un mainloop??? Algo como window.mainloop()???

Comment: soy nuevo en todo lo que tenga que ver con Python, lo que veo en el funcionamiento es que efectivamente si muestra la ventana "window.show()" pero después la oculta y finaliza la ejecución, es decir no la retiene

Comment: Estube viendo un pequeño tutorial, y parece que hay que llamar el metodo exec_ en la app.

Comment: En tu caso seria self.exec_(). Pruebalo y cuentame los resultados c:

Comment: Este es el tutorial: https://medium.com/@hektorprofe/primeros-pasos-en-pyqt-5-y-qt-designer-programas-gr%C3%A1ficos-con-python-6161fba46060

Comment: Cito del tutorial Finalmente pondremos en marcha el bucle del programa con app.exec_(). Si no ponemos esta última línea el programa se iniciará, pero se cerrará inmediatamente.

Comment: efectivamente anexé el siguiente código app.exec_() y funcionó, muchas gracias por tu colaboración !

Comment: @IsraelAntonio Si lo has solucionado podrías responder a tu pregunta tu mismo para que quede constancia en el foro.

Comment: Es un placer c: